# PyECC Example - Python Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I am working with PyECC - it is the only **elliptic curve cryptography** module for python that I can find. I was wondering if anyone had an example of how to use the module? I'll try reading the source, but I couldn't find anything on Stack Overflow on the topic regarding python.

Thanks!

Comment: As this is a wrapper around libseccure, looking at the documentation for [libseccure](http://slideinc.github.com/PyECC/libseccure.html) (to be found at PyECC's github site) could help a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Thank you for your suggestions. For anyone wanting information on how to implement PyECC, check out the crypto wrapper I wrote on github.

[CryptoWrapper](https://github.com/f47h3r/CryptoWrapper) - https://github.com/f47h3r/CryptoWrapper

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the documentation is bare, so the source is the only spot you'll be able to use to figure out how to use the python bindings.  However, it looks like

```
>>> encrypter = ECC.generate()
>>> encrypter.encrypt('your text here')
```

Should work for encryption.  The same should work for all the methods defined in `pyecc.py`, namely `decrypt`, `sign`, and `verify`.  Just be sure to check the method signatures to find out what arguments are required.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/bwesterb/py-seccure
Its Simple Elliptic Curve Cryptography for Python compatible with the excellent SECCURE command line utility.